# Redhat linux 7 - dmidecode - command not found

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm new to linux but can't find any answers elsewhere.

I have a vanilla RHEL 7.1 installation and I want to run dmidecode and lshal, but when I attempt to run it it says "bash: command not found" for both these commands

I have tried /usr/bin and /usr/sbin

Would these commands be in another folder or do they have to be installed ? If the latter, how do I install them ? or are there alternatives..etc !

thanks

Comment: Have you tried to install it using "yum install dmidecode",?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dmidecode` should come with your RHEL 7 install but for good measure run this command to check if it's installed:

```
rpm -qil dmidecode
```

You should get a bunch of information regarding the package. Look for the "Installed Date" line for confirmation. If it's not installed, try a quick:

```
sudo yum install dmidecode
```

`dmidecode` may intentionally be omitted from the install if your system architecture is IBM System Z, PowerPC, or Itanium. From the [RHEL customer portal](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/173553)(requires login to view fully):

> IBM System z (s390) and PowerPC architectures do not use the DMI
>   standard and, consequently, do not have DMI tables to decode, so there
>   is no dmidecode utility available in Red Hat Enterprise Linux for IBM
>   System z (s390) or PowerPC systems. If the python-dmidecode module is
>   installed on these systems, however, the module can read supplied DMI
>   data from x86-based systems.

Also, from this [RHEL bugzilla page](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=296441):

> ...dmidecode should be present in both the
>   i386 and x86_64 kernel-utils, but is not in the powerpc or itanium
>   versions (though in glancing through the spec file, it looks like we
>   do mention dmidecode even on those platforms)

If your system architecture is one of the above, you may consider an alternative such as `lshw` or `hwinfo`. You can make use of the `arch` or `uname -m` commands to show your system architecture.

If you're running a supported platform for dmidecode, consider filing a bug at the location of that second link above^

Comment: Thanks your comment inspired me to look at installing dmidecode and I found that "yum install dmidecode" did just that. This is just a vmware vm that we use for testing stuff that we don't even really understand ! So presumably the guy who set this up didn't tick the right options and dmidecode didn't arrive. Now that I've run that yum command it works. He also didn't install a gui, so when we boot it its just a terminal screen. We're not supported - just a windows dev team that have to do a bit of linux occasionally

Comment: ^^ posted before your edit. but thats clearly the answer, so thanks again

Comment: Yeah, just a quick edit to make things more comprehensive. Thanks and glad you're up and running with it now :)